# Navigation with camera and bounding boxes

Tags: computer-vision, navigation, robotics

I have a 2D image taken with a camera at an arbitrary location within a 3D scene and a set of axis-aligned bounding boxes corresponding to the visible objects with the scene. The visible object outlines are roughly consistent with the edges of their bounding boxes and the objects are opaque. Does anyone know of a fast, low-storage algorithm to determine the location and orientation of the camera focal point (it's safe to assume there is only one solution in this case)?

Comment: Just hunting about.. perhaps this is relevant: "Adaptive edge detection for robust model-based camera tracking"

Comment: what do you mean by "a set of axis-aligned bounding boxes corresponding to the visible objects with the scene"?

Comment: i mean that each visible object has an axis-aligned bounding box. The boxes make up a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything wrong with [P3P](http://www.mmrc.iss.ac.cn/~xgao/paper/ieee.pdf), for example as [implemented](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp) in OpenCV? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

There are, in fact, fast and low-storage algorithms to solve this problem. One became a fairly successful commercial product in 1999, when a fast PC's CPU was clocked at somewhat less than 0.7 GHz, and RAM cost about 10Mbit/USD. It's name was [Canoma](http://www.canoma.com/).

A very similar system was described in Paul Debevec's PhD thesis at about the same time, see [here](http://www.pauldebevec.com/Thesis/debevec-phdthesis-1996_ch5_facade.pdf) for details

Comment: ok - Perspective-3-Point looks good. OpenCV has three methods of solving the problem based on the docs. 
Canoma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canoma) and Mr Debevec used photogrammetry, where the camera must be moved to take two different views of the same object.

Comment: Nope, Canoma allowed model-based calibration from one view. That was actually the main selling point: model your scene as a bunch of perspectively foreshortened box-like things, the the app computed the camera calibration and pose from them.

Comment: i stand corrected. It was the "taken from various angles" that got me http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canoma ;). Thanks for your help.